# When should I close the sql connection of singleton class

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I using a singleton database connection class to connect to MySql database in my PHP project.

```
// the singleton method
public static function getDatabaseConnection()
{
    if (self::$databaseConnection == null)
    {
        self::$databaseConnection = new DatabaseConnection();
        self::$databaseConnection->connect();
    }
    return self::$databaseConnection;
}

private function connect()
{
    $this->connection = new mysqli($this->hostName, $this->username, $this->password, $this->databaseName) 
            or die (mysqli_connect_error());
}

// When should I call this method?!
public function close_connection() {
    if (isset($this->connection)) {
        $this->connection->close();
    }
}
```

while initializing the singleton object it will be connected to the database.

I am just don't know when should I close this connection? Is it save to not close it?

Any additional tip will be very grateful, Thanks.

Comment: PHP will close it on script termination. You don't need to manually close it ever, really. If you have a reason you want to re-establish it, you could close and reopen it.

Comment: Note: I see a `mysql_error()` in there, when you are otherwise connecting to `mysqli`.  The 2 APIs are _not compatible_. You should be checking `mysqli_connect_error()` http://us3.php.net/mysqli_connect_error

Comment: It had been edited, thanks for the catch. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would tend *not* to retain a permanent connection to the database for the lifespan of the singleton.

Leave it up to `mysqli` to manage the connection lifespan - to `MySql` it is [relatively cheap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3479595/314291) to obtain a new connection to the database, or alternatively, you can make use of persisted connections (connection pool) by [prefixing the hostname with `p:`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli.persistconns.html)

Rationale:

- If you aren't actively using the connection all the time in the
  singleton, another component of your app may need the connection and
  make better use of it.
- Also, by releasing connections as soon as they are no longer needed,
  you will pick up bugs quicker, e.g. where you have an uncommitted
  transaction.
- And finally, if the connection to the database is dropped, your
  singleton will need to re-connect in any event.

**TL;DR** - connect, use and disconnect as quickly as possible from your singleton, just like any other consumer.